# How to ensure that updating to database on certain interval

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, java-8

I am working in a application Spring java8
I have one function that generate Labels(pdf generation) asynchronously.
it contains a loop, usually it will run more than 1000, it generate more than 1000 pdf labels.
after every loop ends we need to update the database, so that we just saving the status, ie initially it save numberOfgeneratedCount=0 , after each label we just increment the variable and update the table.
It is not Necessary to save this incremented count to db at every loop ends, what we need is in a fixed intervals only we need to update the database to reduce load on dataBase inserts.
currently my code is like

```
// Label is a database model class labeldb is variable of that 
//commonDao.saveLabelToDb function to save Label object

int numberOfgeneratedCount =0;
labeldb.setProcessedOrderCount(numberOfgeneratedCount);
commonDao.saveLabelToDb(labeldb);

for(Order order: orders){
  generated = true;
  try{
        // pdf generation code
     }catch Exception e{
        // catch block here
        generated = false;
     }

     if(generated){
          numberOfgeneratedCount++;
          deliveryLabeldb.setProcessedOrderCount(numberOfgeneratedCount);
          commonDao.saveLabelToDb(labeldb );
     }
}
```

to improve the performance we need to update database only an interval of 10 seconds. Any help would appreciated

Comment: why don't you update db after for loop completes instead of each iteration of for loop..

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar
it is a time consuming process, so FE needs to know the current status of pdf generation, while the pressing the download button we will show them the status, until the file generation process compleates, it is like numberOfgeneratedCount/total orders

Comment: Move this logic to the server (to stored procedure). *to improve the performance we need to update database only an interval of 10 seconds.* Create scheduled event procedure.

Comment: @Akina i need to achieve this trough code only, because. we might have multiple threads running to generate different types of labels, moving this db is difficult

Comment: @Faseela OK. one possible solution would be hitting the database after certain numbers of pdf generated say 10 or as per your need , for that you can maintain a counter and after db hit reset the counter.

Comment: Thats okay, we can take the reminder of numberOfgeneratedCount/10==0, and update, but what i need is in certain interval

Comment: i am seeking some java solution to this, with some delay or something like that

Comment: Why is it time-consuming?

Comment: *we might have multiple threads running to generate different types of labels, moving this db is difficult* Well, 1st recommendation is not applicable, I see. But the 2nd one - generate labels then create schedule which will execute after 10 sec and update the database is applicable it seems - your code knows everything about the labels generated by it, so it can create specific schedule.

Comment: Generating the label is probably more effort than the UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using the following code, I am not sure about whether this is a good solution, Some one please improve this using some built in functions

```
int numberOfgeneratedCount =0;
labeldb.setProcessedOrderCount(numberOfgeneratedCount);
commonDao.saveLabelToDb(labeldb);
int nowSecs =LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay();
int lastSecs = nowSecs;

for(Order order: orders){
  nowSecs = LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay();
  generated = true;
  try{
        // pdf generation code
     }catch Exception e{
        // catch block here
        generated = false;
     }

     if(generated){
          numberOfgeneratedCount++;
          deliveryLabeldb.setProcessedOrderCount(numberOfgeneratedCount);
          if(nowSecs-lastSecs > 10){
                lastSecs=nowSecs;
                commonDao.saveLabelToDb(labeldb );
             }
        
     }
}
```

Comment: I think, with this you will never reach to save statement..

Comment: Sorry , i forgot to aad a statement of updating nowSec at the begging of the loop

nowSec =LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay();